# Compute $\frac{dy}{dx}$ as a function of $y$ when $x=\cos y$

Tags: derivatives

The function $\cos^{-1}(x)$ is defined for $-1\leq x\leq1$ and $0\leq y\leq \pi$ by the equivalence

$$y=\cos^{-1}(x)\Leftrightarrow x=\cos y$$

**(a) Compute $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$ as a function of $y$ by differentiating the second equation in $(1)$.**

(b) Use the identity $\sin y=\sqrt{1-\cos^2 y}$ and make the substitution $x=\cos y$ in (a) to prove that

$$\dfrac{d}{dx}\cos^{-1}(x)=\frac{-1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

Comment: better to write the question, not to attach a low quality picture

Comment: Are you aware that $dy/dx = 1/(dx/dy)$? Do you know how to differentiate $x = \cos y$ with respect to $y$? Combining these two things is enough to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**DISCLAIMER: See this answer only after you have attempted to solve the problem yourself.**

I am providing an answer for future reference. First differentiate both sides and utilize the chain rule.

$$\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}(x)&=\frac{dy}{dx}\frac{d}{dy}(\cos(y))\\
1&=\frac{dy}{dx}(-\sin(y))
\end{align}
$$
Dividing both sides by $-\sin(y)$ we obtain.
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{dy}{dx}&=\frac{-1}{\sin(y)}\\
&=\frac{-1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}
\end{align}
$$

In the last part we used the substitution $\sin(y)=\sqrt{1-cos^2(y)}=\sqrt{1-x^2}$. Furthermore, since $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{d}{dx}cos^{-1}(x)$ we have established the fact that
$$\frac{d}{dx}cos^{-1}(x)=\frac{-1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

Comment: Crap,beat me to it.I need to get faster at using MathDL.......lol